# Draw a link from the database and add it to the HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to make a page where the  element will redirect the user to a random page from the database.
I made the HTML code, but I can not deal with PHP and MySQL - I was able to connect to the database, but any attempt to connect the MySQL code with the  tag ended in a loss.
Can I count on help writing a PHP script and linking code with ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Subrayada" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Random it</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <header></header>
            <div class="random">
            <a href="">Random</a>
            </div>
            <?php
                require_once "connect.php";
                $conn = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

                $sql = "SELECT link FROM randomit ORDER BY RAND()";




            ?>
            <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 stylesheets pointing to google fonts while it can be 1. 1 Stylesheet will always load faster than 2 since the server only needs 1 request

Comment: I know, it's irrelevant now, but thanks for a tip ;)

Comment: So, basically you need a developer but instead of hiring one you prefer someone here to do it for free?

Comment: You need to read some tutorials before starting to code. What you're asking is usually referenced in any introduction to PHP/MySQL tutorial.

Comment: So, could you help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's try this:

Put this `PHP` part at the **top of the page**;

```
<?php
// set a default link in case something goes wrong
$DEFAULT_LINK = "default.html";
// connect to DB
require_once "connect.php";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
// set query -> get 1 result only with LIMIT 1
$sql = "SELECT link FROM randomit ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result !== false)
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
else
  $row = false;
// if we have a valid result => use it
// else => use the default
if ($row && isset($row["link"]))
  $RANDOM_LINK = $row["link"];
else
  $RANDOM_LINK = $DEFAULT_LINK;
?>
```

And now the `HTML` part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- head part... -->
<body>
<header></header>
<div class="random">
  <a href="<?php echo $RANDOM_LINK; ?>">Random</a>
</div>
<footer></footer>
<!-- etc... -->
```

Comment: I think its bad practice to suppress errors by using `@` in any circumstance. When going into production you might want to suppress all errors but not with an `@`.

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean" What should i do with this problem?

Comment: Hm. I made some changes, try now.

Comment: You forgot ; in $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result), but all works, YOU'RE AWESOME, Thanks :D